# Rewriting an infinite sum

Tags: summation

Rewrite the given expression as a sum whose generic term
involves x^n:

$$
x\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n a_n x^{n-1}) + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(a_k x^{k} )
$$

I get a sum starting at one:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n a_n x^{n}) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n x^{n} ) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+1)a_n x^{n}
$$

Whereas the answer is a similar sum starting at zero.

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_n x^{n}
$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where did the $k=0$ term go?

Comment: I figured that k could be viewed as a dummy variable and exchanged it for one involving n instead. Is this where my error could be?

Comment: Thanks to user2097 for editing

Comment: The second sum in the second displayed identity should start at $n=0$ instead of $n=1$.

Comment: @V.Vocor: Yes, $k$ is a dummy variable, but you don't get to change the lower limit from $k=0$ to $n=1$ just because you rename the variable. The sum should still be from $n=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to write out the first several terms of the expression:  $$x \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^{n-1} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k = x(a_1 x^0 + 2a_2 x^1 + 3a_3 x^2 + \cdots) + (a_0 x^0 + a_1 x^1 + a_2 x^2 + \cdots).$$  Now equating like powers of $x$ gives the result $$a_0 x^0 + 2a_1 x^1 + 3a_2 x^2 + \cdots.$$  This suggests that the general term should have the form $(n+1)a_n x^n$, for $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$.  All that remains is to formalize this by expressing the summands with corresponding indices of summation.

Comment: This is a helpful answer as well. Thanks!